# Simpler way to extract occurrences without using strtok in C

Tags: c, pointers, substring, extract

I'm trying to extract the strings before and after the first comma from the given string. However, I feel there's got to be a better way than what I have below, perhaps I don't even need the `strdup` calls. Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int extract_names(const char *str)
{
    char *name, *last, *p1, *p2, *p3;

    name = strdup(str);
    last = strdup(str);

    p1 = strchr(name, ',');
    if (p1)
    {
        *p1 = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }

    p2 = strchr(last, ',');
    p2++;
    if (p2)
    {
        p3 = strpbrk(p2 + 1, " \0");
        if (p3)
            *p3 = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", p2);
    }
    free(name);
    free(last);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // strings should at least contain last,name.
    // but can contain several words
    const char *str1 = "jones,bob age,12";
    extract_names(str1);
    const char *str2 = "smith,peter";
    extract_names(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
jones
bob
smith
peter
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Pete Darrow How many words does string ",,"  or "A,,B" contain?

Comment: @Amit output expected is: `jones` & `bob`. or last,name.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the string can contain several words. For instance, `"jones,bob age,12 id,3432"`, however, last and first name are always at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I'd like to preserve the original string. However, the output should be  the string before  the first comma and after the first comma without including the the string after the first space (if any).

Comment: If you are using glibc, `char *name=NULL, *last=NULL;
 sscanf(str, "%m[^,],%ms", &name, &last);
 puts(name);
 puts(last);
 free(name);
 free(last);`

Comment: @Pete Darrow  It seems that you did not understand my question. One more whether  this string "A,,B" contains 3 words  or only 2 words.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If I understand your question only 2 words. Not sure what you mean with `,,` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strchr` to find the limits of the last and first names. Then you can use the precision specifier in `printf` to print just the part of the string you are interested in.

For example:

```
int extract_names(const char *str)
{
    const char *comma = strchr(str, ',');
    const char *name_end = strchr(str, ' ');

    /* name ends at space or end of string */
    if (!name_end) {
        name_end = str + strlen(str);
    }

    /* print last name */
    printf("%.*s\n", (comma - str), str);

    /* print first name */
    printf("%.*s\n", name_end - comma, comma + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like how printf is used in this case. Should it be `int extract_names(char *str)` instead of `const char *str`?

Comment: The string is never changed inside the function. So `const char *` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're obviously trying to learn, I'll only give you a few pointers and not a "better working solution".

`strdup` is a useful idea here. As you do, it allows you to overwrite the string (`const char *str` is "readonly").

This combination:

```
p2 = strchr(last, ',');
p2++;
if (p2) {
```

is wrong. after the call `p2` equals the return value. if you advance it before the `if`, you're not testing anything (if NULL was returned, it's 1 by the time you test it).

You don't need two `strdup`s, and you don't need to search twice. `p1` already points to the right place in `name`, you can use that for the rest of your logic.